# GCC/Linker error: using extern keyword gives duplicate definition

Tags: c, gcc, linker, extern

I read [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/) that the `extern` keyword can be used in combination with an initialization which would be translated into an actual definition according to C standard.

First of all I couldn't really find an actual passage defining this specific condition in the current [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (draft). Page 158ff only gives examples without initialization.

Further on, when I try to compile the following:

testfile.h

```
extern int var1=10;
void testFcn(void);
```

testfile.c

```
#include "testfile.h"
void testFcn(void){
    int var3 = var1;
}
```

main.c

```
#include "testfile.h"
void main(void){
    testFcn();
}
```

..my compiler (gcc/5.4.1) warns me about the following:

```
testfile.h:1:12: warning: ‘var1’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
 extern int var1=10;
            ^
In file included from testfile.c:1:0:
testfile.h:1:12: warning: ‘var1’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
 extern int var1=10;
            ^
```

And the linker throws an error confirming that there's a duplicate definition:

```
/tmp/ccE8M7S0.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `var1'
/tmp/cc7OrQEI.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I understand the compiler warnings but not the linker error. <s>Shouldn't the linker replace the *testfile* reference with the object code of the very same file</s>? I know how to implement it in a better way (i.e. defining objects only in source files) but I want to understand why this specific arrangement won't work.

---

Conclusion from the discussion below:

My main confusion was that I expected the pre-processor and the linker to pass this kind of information onto each other where certain object definitions are coming from. Now I realize it's nonsense but I thought the linker should have gotten the information from the pre-processor that the variable `var` was defined in *testfile.h*. In other words the linker was supposed to merge those two definitions. But that's what the `static` keyword is for.
Thank you to all who were helping to clear that up.

---

<sup>**Edit1**: Changed initialization value to 10 since initialization to 0 seemed to distract from the actual problem. And pointed out that doing it differently would be definitely be the way to go to solve the problem but I'd like to understand it completely, first.</sup>

<sup>**Edit2**: Adding conclusion.</sup>

Comment: "Shouldn't the linker replace the testfile reference with the object code of the very same file?" This is very unclear. Please elaborate. What "testfile reference"? There are two object files, each containing a definition of var1. What should the linker replace and where? It doesn't normally replace definitions.

Comment: @n.m. I think my main confusion was about the fact that I expected the pre-processor and the linker to pass this kind of information (i.e. in which file an object was defined) onto each other. But that's nonsense, of course. Now I understand. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard specifies:

> If  the  declaration  of  an  identifier  for  an  object  has  file 
>   scope  and  an  initializer,  the declaration is an external
>   definition for the identifier.
>
> A declaration  of  an  identifier  for  an  object  that  has  file 
>   scope  without  an  initializer, and without a storage-class specifier
>   or with the storage-class specifier `static`, constitutes a *tentative
>   definition*. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative
>   definitions for an identifier, and  the  translation  unit  contains 
>   no  external  definition  for  that  identifier, then the  behavior 
>   is  exactly  as  if  the  translation  unit  contains  a  file  scope 
>   declaration  of  that identifier, with the composite type as of the
>   end of the translation unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

(C2011, 6.9.2/1-2)

Thus, if your header contains

> ```
> extern int var1=10;
> ```

then every file that includes it contains an (external) *definition* of `var1`.  Furthermore, if it contains just

```
int var1;
```

, and there is no other file-scope declaration of `var1` that designates it `extern` in the translation unit, then that translation unit also contains a definition of `var1`.  If there is no declaration designating it `static`, then that declaration furthermore is an *external* declaration, because external linkage is the default for file-scope declarations.

But the standard specifies that:

> An *external  definition* is  an  external  declaration  that  is 
>   also  a  definition  of  a  function (other  than  an  inline 
>   definition)  or  an  object.  If an identifier declared with external
>   linkage  is  used  in  an  expression  (other  than  as  part  of  the
>   operand  of  a `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator  whose  result  is  an 
>   integer  constant), [then] somewhere  in  the  entire program  there 
>   shall  be  exactly  one external  definition  for  the  identifier; 
>   otherwise, **there shall be no more than one**.

(C2011, 6.9/5; emphasis added)

Thus, if you put an external definition of a variable in a header file (as in your example), and include that header in more than one source file contributing to the same program or library, then you violate a constraint of the standard.

C does not specify particular behaviors for the innumerable ways in which a program can fail to conform, so what the linker actually does with such code is a question of implementation detail.  In many cases, however, if there is an external definition of an object in a given translation unit, then the compiler will allocate storage and associate an externally-visible symbol with it in the corresponding object file.

When a linker is faced with two or more object files containing identical strong symbols, it has a conundrum: which does it use?  Some error out.  Some, under certain circumstances, merge the symbols and the objects to which they refer.

> Shouldn't the linker replace the testfile reference with the object code of the very same file?

There's no "should" or "should not" with respect to non-conforming code.  Moreover, the standard specifies:

> In  the  set  of  translation  units  and  libraries  that  constitutes an  entire  program,  each declaration  of  a  particular  identifier  with external  linkage denotes  the  same  object  or function.

(C2011, 6.2.2/2)

So no, it is not reasonable to suppose that the linker should just choose the object defined in the same translation unit, though it is conceivable that indeed some do so.  But if that's what you want then you should declare the object with *internal* linkage -- that is, declare it with the `static` storage-class specifier.  In that case, the declaration generally should not appear in a header at all, as that would give every translation unit that includes the header its own copy of the variable, which is not usually wanted.

---

For the record, if you want to provide an external variable then the way to do so is with an external declaration *that is not a definition* in a header file:

#### my.h

```
extern int foo;
```

combined with a definition in exactly one source file, for example:

#### my.c

```
extern int foo = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

`extern` doesn't allocate memory, it just declares the variable.So don't assign the variable like you did in the header file.Instead, include this variable declaration to another file and use it.
In your program, since you have defined the variable `var1`twice (in header and .c file) the error arised.Using `extern`as shown below will now cause the linker to point to the same `var1`

testfile.h

```
extern int var1;
void testFcn(void);
```

testfile.c

```
#include "testfile.h"

int var1 = 10;
void testFcn(void){
    int var3 = var1;
}
```

Comment: `extern` with an initializer is a *definition*, which does allocate the memory.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think in this example extern made 'var1' to be declared in header file so that it can be defined in .c file which then actually allocates memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
extern int var1=0;
```

This is a definition, but your header must contain declaration:

```
extern int var1;
```

And there must be only one definition across whole program. Typically it should be in of the `.c` sources. Also `extern` is redundant` in this case:

```
int var1 = 0;
```

Moreover, globals are initialized with zeros by default, so you may skip that initializer.

Comment: Not fully agreeing here or maybe I did not understand what you were trying to say. But the header could also include a definition of the variable which is fine as well. So why is the initialization causing an error. In both cases it's the same memory allocation. One is manually initialized the other per default to 0.

Comment: @JimMcAdams Of course, headers may contain whatever code you want. But when you put definition into header it leads to creating of memory object with the same name in each translation unit that includes that header. These are different allocations, but they have the same name. And linker simply can not choose which of these objects should be used by program.

Comment: so you are including the definition twice, right? That's "duplicate definition".

Comment: @Serhio Exactly, but that's where my confusion grows. Why does it translate into two different object declarations although it's only referenced once. The main.c reference should be completely replaced by the testfile.c translation or am I wrong?

Comment: Replaced? Why would that? they are in the same global scope. Both having external linkage. If you want it to "replace" you need to have them `static` rather than `external`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm talking about the linker and the reference in the main.o to testfile.o. I expect the testfile.o part to be put in where the "#include "testfile.h"" reference is in the main.c.

Comment: The linker sees two object files with the *same* symbol with external linkage defined. External linkage means that every object file has the access to this symbol. So now, once your testfile.o is referring to your `var1`, the linker cannot tell to which one it is actually referring. This is how external linkage works. If it doesn't work for you, it means that you are doing it wrong. Use `static` instead.

Comment: Thank you @EugeneSh. I think my main confusion was about the fact that I expected the pre-processor and the linker to pass this kind of information onto each other. But that's nonsense, of course. Now I understand. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't initialize the variable in the header.

You need to declare it in a header, and define / initialize it in one and only one of your '.c' files.

Comment: I know it's not good practice and like I said, I know how to do it better. But what exactly is the initialization of the variable causing the linker to do?

Comment: @JimMcAdams: Each file that includes the header defines the global variable.  C++ has the ODR — One Definition Rule.  You can't define a global variable more than once.  So, the linker correctly complains that the variable is multiply defined because each file that includes the header defines the variable.  Remember, headers are crude text copying services. The compiler doesn't really know about the header; it just sees the text from the output of the preprocessor.  (That's an over-simplification, but as far as the variable definition is concerned, it's accurate enough.)

Comment: The exact details are somewhat implementation defined, but in general, the linker sees a symbol `var1` defined in the [data section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) for the object code resulting from compiling `testfile.c` and again in the object file for `main.c`.  It doesn't know what to do with that so it throws an error.  Analogy time:  Think of each variable as a house on a street and its *symbol name* as a street address. You're trying to build two houses on the same street with the same address and expecting the post office to work it out.